# Extract Pages from PDF based on search in python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pdf

Everything is working fine except timing.
it takes lot time for my file containing 1000 pages and having 100 pages of interest.

```
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
import glob, os

# find pages
def  findText(f, slist):
    file = open(f, 'rb')
    pdfDoc = PdfFileReader(file)
    pages = []
    for i in range(pdfDoc.getNumPages()):
        content = pdfDoc.getPage(i).extractText().lower()
        for s in slist:
            if re.search(s.lower(), content) is not None:
                if i not in pages:
                    pages.append(i)
    return pages

#extract pages
def extractPage(f, fOut, pages):
    file = open(f, 'rb')
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    pdfOne = PdfFileReader(file)
    for i in pages:
        output.addPage(pdfOne.getPage(i))
    outputStream = open(fOut, "wb")
    output.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()
    return

os.chdir(r"path\to\mydir")
for pdfFile in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
    print(pdfFile)
    outPdfFile = pdfFile.replace(".pdf","_searched_extracted.pdf")
    stringList = ["string1", "string2"]
    extractPage(pdfFile, outPdfFile, findText(pdfFile, stringList))
```

Updated code after suggestions is at:

https://gist.github.com/pra007/099f10b07be5b7126a36438c67ad7a1f

Comment: We don't really care about the overall time but more about the specifics. Instead of `python file.py`, use `python -m cProfile -s cumtime file.py` and post the functions that took the most time.

Comment: is my modified code OK?

Comment: I have rolled back the question to Rev 1. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep in mind next time not to change the question.

Answer (score 4):

You could try profiling but the code is simple enough that I think you're spending most of the time in PyPDF2 code. Two options:

- You can preprocess your PDF files to store their text somewhere, which will make the search phase much faster, especially if you run multiples queries on the same PDF files
- You can try another parser such as a Python 3 version of PDFMiner, or even a parser written in a faster language

Comment: Thanks. I thought pdfminer is dead. let me test pdfminer3k

Comment: @Rahul Preprocessing sounds better. It's not an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might help a lot is to compile your regexs just once.  Instead of

```
def findText(f, slist):
    file = open(f, 'rb')
    pdfDoc = PdfFileReader(file)
    pages = []
    for i in range(pdfDoc.getNumPages()):
        content = pdfDoc.getPage(i).extractText().lower()
        for s in slist:
            if re.search(s.lower(), content) is not None:
                if i not in pages:
                    pages.append(i)
    return pages
```

try:

```
def  findText(f, slist):
    file = open(f, 'rb')
    pdfDoc = PdfFileReader(file)
    pages = []
    searches = [ re.compile(s.lower()) for s in slist ]
    for i in range(pdfDoc.getNumPages()):
        content = pdfDoc.getPage(i).extractText().lower()
        for s in searches:
            if s.search(content) is not None:
                if i not in pages:
                    pages.append(i)
    return pages
```

Also, you can short-circuit out a lot faster than you're doing:

```
def  findText(f, slist):
    file = open(f, 'rb')
    pdfDoc = PdfFileReader(file)
    pages = []
    searches = [ re.compile(s.lower()) for s in slist ]
    for i in range(pdfDoc.getNumPages()):
        content = pdfDoc.getPage(i).extractText().lower()
        for s in searches:
            if s.search(content) is not None:
                pages.append(i)
                break
    return pages
```